# Join List<List<String>> into a single string with delimiter

Tags: c#, linq

I need to join `List<List<String>>` into a single string where each inner `List<String>` is joined with `", "` as the delimiter, but the entire joined string is enclosed in `"("` and `")"`. All those joined strings are then joined together with `", "` as the delimiter.

I know how to do this using simple `foreach` but I am looking for ways to do this using LINQ.

```
private String MyMethod(List<List<String>> listOfListOfvalues)
{
    // Input =>
    //
    //    List<List<String>> listOfListOfvalues = new List<List<String>>();
    //    listOfListOfvalues.Add(new List<String>() { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
    //    listOfListOfvalues.Add(new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C" });
    //    listOfListOfvalues.Add(new List<String>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
    //
    // Desired output of the method =>
    // 
    //    "(a, b, c, d), (A, B, C), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"

    List<String> listOfJoinedValues = new List<String>();
    foreach (List<String> ListOfvalues in listOfListOfvalues)
    {
        listOfJoinedValues.Add("(" + String.Join(", ", ListOfvalues) + ")");
    }
    return String.Join(", ", listOfJoinedValues);
}
```

Comment: `string.Join(", ", items.Select(inner => $"({string.Join(", ", inner)})"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) LINQ method to form the inner joined string enclosed in parenthesis and then join the resulted `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
string.Join(", ", listOfListOfvalues.Select(l => "(" + string.Join(", ", l) + ")"));
```

Full example:

```
List<List<string>> listOfListOfvalues = new List<List<string>>();
listOfListOfvalues.Add(new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
listOfListOfvalues.Add(new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" });
listOfListOfvalues.Add(new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });

string joined = 
    string.Join(", ", listOfListOfvalues.Select(l => "(" + string.Join(", ", l) + ")"));
Console.WriteLine(joined);
// Prints: (a, b, c, d), (A, B, C), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```